# How to move datafile to network share folder

Tags: oracle, rename, move

I use Oracle DB in Windows server.
I can't extend disk. So, I want to use network share folder.
To change the path of oracle db to a network shared folder, I executed the command below.

alter database rename file 'C:\oracle\oradata\protect\TEST02.DBF' to '\192.168.63.38\38\NEW\TEST02.DBF';

ORA-01511: Error renaming log/data file
ORA-01141: Error renaming data 7 file - new
The file \192.168.63.38\38\NEW\TEST02.DBF' does not exist

The following error occurs. I've made sure that the file exists in that path.
Is there a format for specifying network share folders?

I was afraid that the service account used by Oracle didn't have permissions, so I changed it to Administrator and confirmed that it was connecting to the direct path.

Comment: Or is the network share folder unavailable?

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I use 12C version.

Comment: 12c Release 2 ?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
Yes. This is exactly version.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not clear on whether a Windows network share is a supported location for datafile storage. Rather, it talks about direct NFS storage. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ssdbi/supported-storage-options-for-oracle-database.html#GUID-120C3995-F827-4D01-B955-CB1BD0457AF7

If an NTFS network share is to be attempted, I believe you must at a minimum mount the share to a drive letter. Once you do that, use the following command (using the E: drive as an example) to relocate the file while it is online:

```
ALTER DATABASE MOVE DATAFILE 'C:\oracle\oradata\protect\TEST02.DBF' TO 'E:\38\NEW\TEST02.DBF';
```